# My closest() code is not working. Why?

Tags: jquery

Look at the following snippet. I have the following structure of code.

**Working Snippet using `parent()'**

```js
function ModifyValue(name, current){
    var qty = $(current).parent().find('input');
    if ($(current).hasClass('increment')) {
        qty.val(parseInt(qty.val())+1);
    } else {
        qty.val(parseInt(qty.val())-1);
    }          
}
```

```css
input {
    width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group quantity-div">
    <button type="button" class="pls altera" onclick="ModifyValue('testname', this)"> - </button>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="inputbox">&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="pls altera increment" onclick="ModifyValue('newname', this)"> + </button>
</div>
```

The above snippet is working fine when I using the `parent()` selector like `$(current).parent().find('input')`. But It is not working when i try to use the `closest()` like `$(current).closest('input')` like below.

**Not Working Snippet using `closest()`**

```js
function ModifyValue(name, current){
    var qty = $(current).closest('input');
    if ($(current).hasClass('increment')) {
        qty.val(parseInt(qty.val())+1);
    } else {
        qty.val(parseInt(qty.val())-1);
    }          
}
```

```css
input {
    width: 60px;height: 23px;padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group quantity-div">
    <button type="button" class="pls altera" onclick="ModifyValue('testname', this)"> - </button>&nbsp;
    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="inputbox">&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="pls altera increment" onclick="ModifyValue('newname', this)"> + </button>
</div>
```

Is that closest won't find any nearest element like my above code or what I am doing wrong? Help me to understand this.

Comment: Check [doc and difference](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches through the parents of the element **AND** the element itself, not the siblings.

If you want to select an `input` on the same level, you can use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

`$(current).siblings('input')`

```js
function ModifyValue(name, current) {
  var qty = $(current).siblings('input');
  if ($(current).hasClass('increment')) {
    qty.val(parseInt(qty.val()) + 1);
  } else {
    qty.val(parseInt(qty.val()) - 1);
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 60px;
  height: 23px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group quantity-div">
  <button type="button" class="pls altera" onclick="ModifyValue('testname',this)"> - </button>&nbsp;
  <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="inputbox">&nbsp;
  <button type="button" class="pls altera increment" onclick="ModifyValue('newname',this)"> + </button>
</div>
```

Comment: `.closest() searches through the parents of the element`. Is that ture? If I have used `$(current).closest('button').html()` then I am getting the `+` value properly. How that is working? I know the siblings() method will work. But why my code is not working that is my question.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai `.closest()` searches through the parents OR the element itself.

Comment: ohhh ok. Now i got the exact issue. Thank you so much.